# Retrieving data from XML as table in Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle

I don't think what I'm trying to achieve is that dar fetched.

I'm just trying to pass to a procedure an XML string to convert it to a table and use it on a query, but I'm having problems converting the XML to table.

So far this it what I have

```
DECLARE
  xmlVar CLOB := '<DocumentElement><XML_Result><GSID>22271</GSID><FROMCITY>LAREDO</FROMCITY><FROMSTATE>TX</FROMSTATE><FROMPOSTAL>78040</FROMPOSTAL><FROMCOUNTRY>US</FROMCOUNTRY><TOCITY>RAMOSARIZPE</TOCITY><TOSTATE>CU</TOSTATE><TOPOSTAL>25000</TOPOSTAL><TOCOUNTRY>MX</TOCOUNTRY><TOTALMILES>194.9</TOTALMILES></XML_Result></DocumentElement>';
BEGIN

with routes AS (
  Select extractvalue(column_value, '/XML_Result/GSID') GSID,
      extractvalue(column_value, '/XML_Result/FROMCITY') FROMCITY,
      extractvalue(column_value, '/XML_Result/FROMSTATE') FROMSTATE,
      extractvalue(column_value, '/XML_Result/FROMPOSTAL') FROMPOSTAL,
      extractvalue(column_value, '/XML_Result/FROMCOUNTRY') FROMCOUNTRY,
      extractvalue(column_value, '/XML_Result/TOCITY') TOCITY,
      extractvalue(column_value, '/XML_Result/TOSTATE') TOSTATE,
      extractvalue(column_value, '/XML_Result/TOPOSTAL') TOPOSTAL,
      extractvalue(column_value, '/XML_Result/TOCOUNTRY') TOCOUNTRY,
      extractvalue(column_value, '/XML_Result/TOTALMILES') TOTALMILES
  FROM TABLE(XMLSequence(XMLTYPE(xmlVar).extract('//XML_Result')))
) Select * from routes ;

END;
```

I think this should work. I also tested

```
declare
     xmlClob CLOB;
begin

  xmlClob := '<DocumentElement><XML_Result><GSID>22271</GSID><FROMCITY>LAREDO</FROMCITY><FROMSTATE>TX</FROMSTATE><FROMPOSTAL>78040</FROMPOSTAL><FROMCOUNTRY>US</FROMCOUNTRY><TOCITY>RAMOSARIZPE</TOCITY><TOSTATE>CU</TOSTATE><TOPOSTAL>25000</TOPOSTAL><TOCOUNTRY>MX</TOCOUNTRY><TOTALMILES>194.9</TOTALMILES></XML_Result></DocumentElement>';

  Select * from xmltable(
    '//XML_Result'
    PASSING xmltype.createxml(xmlClob)
    COLUMNS GSID VARCHAR(100) PATH 'GSID',
      FROMCITY VARCHAR(100) PATH 'FROMCITY',
      FROMSTATE VARCHAR(100) PATH 'FROMSTATE',
      FROMPOSTAL VARCHAR(100) PATH 'FROMPOSTAL',
      FROMCOUNTRY VARCHAR(100) PATH 'FROMCOUNTRY',
      TOCITY VARCHAR(100) PATH 'TOCITY',
      TOSTATE VARCHAR(100) PATH 'TOSTATE',
      TOPOSTAL VARCHAR(100) PATH 'TOPOSTAL',
      TOCOUNTRY VARCHAR(100) PATH 'TOCOUNTRY',
      TOTALMILES VARCHAR(100) PATH 'TOTALMILES') xms;

end;
```

Both code returns me this error

> PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

But I don't know how to get this. Also, I'm not able to create a table, nor a temporary one, clients restricts me a lot of what I can and can't do.

Any ideas to achieve my intended result?

PS: The xml is a little piece of what I'm working with

EDIT:

I just tested this

```
with routes AS (
  Select extractvalue(column_value, '/XML_Result/GSID') GSID,
      extractvalue(column_value, '/XML_Result/FROMCITY') FROMCITY,
      extractvalue(column_value, '/XML_Result/FROMSTATE') FROMSTATE,
      extractvalue(column_value, '/XML_Result/FROMPOSTAL') FROMPOSTAL,
      extractvalue(column_value, '/XML_Result/FROMCOUNTRY') FROMCOUNTRY,
      extractvalue(column_value, '/XML_Result/TOCITY') TOCITY,
      extractvalue(column_value, '/XML_Result/TOSTATE') TOSTATE,
      extractvalue(column_value, '/XML_Result/TOPOSTAL') TOPOSTAL,
      extractvalue(column_value, '/XML_Result/TOCOUNTRY') TOCOUNTRY,
      extractvalue(column_value, '/XML_Result/TOTALMILES') TOTALMILES
  FROM TABLE(XMLSequence(XMLTYPE('<DocumentElement><XML_Result><GSID>22271</GSID><FROMCITY>LAREDO</FROMCITY><FROMSTATE>TX</FROMSTATE><FROMPOSTAL>78040</FROMPOSTAL><FROMCOUNTRY>US</FROMCOUNTRY><TOCITY>RAMOSARIZPE</TOCITY><TOSTATE>CU</TOSTATE><TOPOSTAL>25000</TOPOSTAL><TOCOUNTRY>MX</TOCOUNTRY><TOTALMILES>194.9</TOTALMILES></XML_Result><XML_Result><GSID>24102</GSID><FROMCITY>DELRIO</FROMCITY><FROMSTATE>TX</FROMSTATE><FROMPOSTAL>78840</FROMPOSTAL><FROMCOUNTRY>US</FROMCOUNTRY><TOCITY>REYNOSA</TOCITY><TOSTATE>TM</TOSTATE><TOPOSTAL>88787</TOPOSTAL><TOCOUNTRY>MX</TOCOUNTRY><TOTALMILES>325.4</TOTALMILES></XML_Result><XML_Result><GSID>23131</GSID><FROMCITY>BROWNSVL</FROMCITY><FROMSTATE>TX</FROMSTATE><FROMPOSTAL>78521</FROMPOSTAL><FROMCOUNTRY>US</FROMCOUNTRY><TOCITY>EAGLEPS</TOCITY><TOSTATE>TX</TOSTATE><TOPOSTAL>78852</TOPOSTAL><TOCOUNTRY>US</TOCOUNTRY><TOTALMILES>326.3</TOTALMILES></XML_Result><XML_Result><GSID>21011</GSID><FROMCITY>EAGLEPS</FROMCITY><FROMSTATE>TX</FROMSTATE><FROMPOSTAL>78852</FROMPOSTAL><FROMCOUNTRY>US</FROMCOUNTRY><TOCITY>BROWNSVL</TOCITY><TOSTATE>TX</TOSTATE><TOPOSTAL>78521</TOPOSTAL><TOCOUNTRY>US</TOCOUNTRY><TOTALMILES>326.2</TOTALMILES></XML_Result></DocumentElement>').extract('//XML_Result')))
) Select * from routes;
```

I'm achieving my intention, as I'm getting a table which I can query in a subquery with another couple of tables, but the issue is, the XML won't be this short. My current xml string is over 4000 characters long, so I'm in need to store it into a variable in order to be able to use it fully.

I'm thinking, maybe, send chunks of the XML, 5 registers at a time, and execute the query with each chunk of XML and then append the results to my DataTable back in C#, but I rather just send the whole XML once and get the whole response

Answer (score 0):

The error has nothing to do with XML: from within a PLSQL block, you can not do `select ... from ...`, but you need to fetch the result into some variable.

For example:

```
SQL> select 1 from dual;

         1
----------
         1

SQL> begin
  2      select 1 from dual;
  3  end;
  4  /
    select 1 from dual;
    *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 5:
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement


SQL> declare
  2      vN number;
  3  begin
  4      select 1 into vN from dual;
  5      dbms_output.put_line(vN);
  6  end;
  7  /
1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Well, I can't store it in a variable, I need it in table form, and I can't create tables due to client constraints

Comment: So what should you do with the result? Do you need to spool it to a file, return some output parameter, ... ?

Comment: I need to get a table from this XML in order to use in another subquery. I updated my question in order to give more insight of my intention